# Websphere - Transformer.setParameter not working

Tags: java, xml, xslt, websphere, transformer-model

I have an XSLT which i use to transform an XML using Java. The code is working fine when i run it in eclipse and use Apache Tomcat. But when i deploy the ear file to WebSphere, the field is showing as blank. Does anyone have ideas?

The java variables 'reportId' and 'proposalId' are set as i used System.out.println() and could see the value is set.

Java Code
    // Use the factory to create a template containing the xsl file

```
Templates template = factory.newTemplates(new StreamSource(is));              

// Use the template to create a transformer
Transformer xformer = template.newTransformer();
xformer.setParameter("reportId", reportId);
xformer.setParameter("proposalId", proposalId);


<xsl:param name="proposalId"/>
<xsl:param name="reportId"/>
```

I then use the following in the XSLT to read the parameter:

`<td align="left"><b>Proposal Ref: </b> <xsl:value-of select="$proposalId"/>
    </td>
    <td align="left"><b>Report Id: </b> <xsl:value-of select="$reportId"/>
    </td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that i had the param inside the template tag. The transformer can not set the value of a template level variable. It can only set it on a global level variable. So my code was like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:param name="proposalId"/>
<xsl:param name="reportId"/>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but it should have been:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:param name="proposalId"/>
<xsl:param name="reportId"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```